# Passing arguments in python setup.py install_requires list

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pyramid, setup.py

I have used pip to install PIL. It requires two additional arguments while installation. So the command for installation looks something like this.

```
pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL
```

I need to add the PIL package in setup.py file. Adding PIL in the `install_requires` list do install PIL but it doesn't work, as I need to install PIL with the additional arguments.

So how can I add the PIL to the `install_requires` list with additional arguments ?

Comment: There is no way to pass extra parameters from setup.py. The problem is that PIL does not host the package on PyPi. As an aside, check out Pillow, it is a fork of PIL that is hosted on PyPi.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to specify extra arguments in `install_requires` in setup.py. But, I solved my problem of installing dependencies with `global-options` by sub-classing `setuptools.command.install` class and overriding its `run()` method, like following code -

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install
from subprocess import call


class CustomInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        call(['pip', 'install', 'PIL', '--allow-external', 'PIL', '--allow-unverified', 'PIL'])

setup( ...
      cmdclass={
          'install': CustomInstall,
      },
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just replace PIL with Pillow (in your install_requires). It's a fork of PIL with bugfixes, py3k support and proper hosting. You don't need to change your code.