# setup.py install_require with options

Tags: python, setup.py

I need to add `rjsmin` to my dependencies via `install_require` in a setup.py.

`rjsmin` offers a way to disable the c-extension by using the `--without-c-extensions` switch like following

```
python setup.py install --without-c-extensions
```

I wonder, how to add this switch to the `install_require` string.

Comment: Although it's not exactly a helpful answer: [*"There is no way to pass extra parameters from setup.py."*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161727/passing-arguments-in-python-setup-py-install-requires-list#comment42307056_25161727)

Comment: @jonrsharpe: it might be possible in pip version 7 and above. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem of installing dependencies with `global-options` by sub-classing `setuptools.command.install` class and overriding its `run()` method, like following code -

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install
from subprocess import call


class CustomInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        call(['pip', 'install', 'pycurl', '--global-option=--with-nss'])

setup( ...
      cmdclass={
          'install': CustomInstall,
      },
)
```

Here, I am installing `pycurl` with global option `--with-nss`

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an `--install-option` or `--global-option` along with the requirement text.

You can refer the [doc here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#per-requirement-overrides)

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know about this option - But i can't rely on pip >= 7.0 :-/

Comment: yeah me myself is using version 1.5.6 :D

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on pip 19.0.3. It works in requirements.txt, but not in install_requires.